# Ambigous use of 'init(CIImage:)'

Tags: swift

I have an error - `Ambigous use of 'init(CIImage:)'` on the last line. Can anyone help me fix it?

```
let origImage = CIImage(image: img)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
filter?.setValue(origImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let invertedImage = UIImage(CIImage: (filter?.outputImage)!)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43528115/2303865

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, `UIImage(CIImage: ...)` constructor was renamed to:

```
let invertedImage = UIImage(ciImage: ...)
```